# When i want to create workspace it give me an error

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, catkin, ros-fuerte, rosws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I try to set up my workspace for ROS Lunar, but when i run the comand `rosws set ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox`  it give me this error: `ERROR in config: Command requires a target workspace.`

I followed the steps in the tutorial on [ROS.ORG](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment) site.

After that I tried `Catkin` instead of `rosbuild`.
The comands i entered are in this order:

1. `mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src`
2. `cd ~/catkin_ws/`
3. `catkin_make`

After this point i get the next error:

```
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/lunar
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/lunar
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/ovidiu/anaconda3/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gmock will be built
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /home/ovidiu/anaconda3/bin/nosetests
CMake Error at /opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/home/ovidiu/anaconda3/bin/python
  "/opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code No such file or directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:74 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:163 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I also want to mention that i had anaconda3 installed but I uninstalled it.

If someone could help me i would be grateful.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333270/when-i-want-to-create-workspace-it-give-me-an-error/) by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-18**:\

> I try to set up my workspace for ROS Lunar, but when i run the comand

can you clarify why you call your workspace `fuerte_sandbox` in that case and try to use `rosws`? Since Groovy we typically use Catkin workspaces and `rosws` is rarely used.

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-09-18**:
I followed the instruction on the link I mentioned. At point 3 i stuck. I will try with Catkin.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-18**:\

> I followed the instruction on the link I mentioned.

The `rosbuild` option is deprecated and only there for historical/archival reasons. The default is Catkin.

> I tried with Catkin but it give me this message:

please update your original question with the error. Comments are too small for that.

Include *all* commands that you enter that lead up to the error.

Use the `edit` button/link and append the new information to your current text.

Do not post a new question.

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-09-18**:
Ok. I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You appear to have Anaconda installed and active:

> ```
> -- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/ovidiu/anaconda3/bin/python
> ```

that is going to cause problems, as the ROS Python packages are not installed in that environment.

Please deactivate Anaconda (ie: remove it from your `PATH`) and try again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-09-18**:
How can I do that?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-18**:
Most likely by:

> remov[ing] it from your `PATH`

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-09-18**:
I uninstalled safe anaconda... but the PYTHON_EXECUTABLE path didn't changed.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-18**:
Delete the `build` and `devel` folders in the workspace. The paths are cached in those.

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-09-18**:
Yes. I deleted entire `catkin_ws`  folder and i run again the commands I wrote before.

Thanks a lot!!!!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-18**:
Could you please mark the question as answered by ticking the checkmark (✓) to the left of the answer if you feel it has been answered? Thanks.